# How to clear contents of UIWebView in Detail View of UISplitView

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a web view in the detail view. When object selected from master view (UITableView) is loads its contents in the web view. When I traverse back in the master view the contents in web view still remain. I want to clear up the contents of web view. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a delegate that is called when the you move back to the master view 
and in this call:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString :@"document.open();document.close()"];
```

Comment: thanks for the help. it works really very fine. the way i wished it to happen

Comment: Well the solution worked well for ppt, doc, and txt files. But when a pdf is loaded in the web view then this sloution seems to be a failure. Is there some common sloution which can be used for all the file types. Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried out using the following and it worked out for me.        [appDelegate.detailView.objWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><head></head><body></body></html>" baseURL:nil];      
 Now any of the file type open in web view gets cleared on clicking else where